# How to add SQL Server database file to a C# project?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm a beginner using C# and SQL Server, I was about to share the project but my database still needs the main `Database.mdf` file even after install the project, the question is how to insert or attach a clean database file (with same tables & columns) into the installed project without errors?

By the way, my project enables anyone to collect information about "Name, Age, and Gender"

```
string constring = (@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\pro pc\Documents\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
string Query = "insert into Sample (Name,Age,Gender) values ('" + this.txtname.Text + "','" + this.txtage.Text + "','" + this.gender + "')";

SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(constring);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, cn);
SqlDataReader rd;

try
{
    cn.Open();
    rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    MessageBox.Show("Saved", "Saving Record");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Are you using that SQL Database.mdf as a local (pertinent to the User or Machine), or as a shared centralized Database?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Alex Bell - I don't know about a local/shared staff, I'm still beginner but I'll be glad if you give me some notes

Comment: marc_s - I searched for *parametrized queries*, hope if you've a good tutorial for this!

Answer (score 0):

Script ID:

> The project key of the script to be executed. To find the project key,
>   open the project in the script editor, then select File > Project
>   properties.

Source: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution/rest/v1/scripts/run#path-parameters